# How can I make a search form that can search taxonomies and posts?

Tags: search, filters, dropdown

I have a search bar on the homepage of my theme. I want the user to be able to select from a drop down to search for everything, posts, or taxonomies. I looked at the wp_dropdown function, but its meant for searching under a single tag, and not within a taxonomie group.

now I just have a html dropdown next to the search form. how can I use the selection from the dropdown to modify the search?

Heres the code im working with

```
<form class="searchform" method="get" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="hidden">Search form</legend>
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input class="search" name="s" type="text" value="Search Here"/>
            </div>
            <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform" style="display: none; ">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Everything</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1">People</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="2">Schools</option>
            </select>
            <button value="submit" class="searchBtn"><span class="hidden">Submit</span></button>
            <!--END #searchform-->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would do the trick.

**EDIT**

My code assumes the querystring value is the post_type, not an integer like your form field. Also, your form field is named 'cat', I think WordPress has that reserved, at least I remember having conflicts when I last used 'cat' in a querystring.

**EDIT 2**

(Changed filter from 'posts_where' to 'pre_get_posts' after having done some tests)

In functions.php

```
 function my_filter( $query )
 {
      if( is_search() )
      {
           $type = ( !empty( $_GET['your-field'] ) ) ? $_GET['your-field'] : "";

           if( $type )
                $query->set( 'post_type', $type );
      }
 }
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_filter' );
```

Comment: thanks this is perfect but how exactly do I implement it?

Comment: You're using WordPress' search, right? Or are you using something custom? If it's WordPress', all you need is to put the code above in your functions.php, and change your 'option' values to the post_type

Comment: Ok so this works great for searching post types, but how can I get this to work for taxonomy types?

Comment: @StevenBaltay Set the `tax_query` parameter : `$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );`

Comment: For information on the `tax_query` parameter : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: tax_query is used for showing posts relating to a taxonomy. I need a physical list of the taxonomies themselves to be searched and shown. BTW thanks for the help.

Comment: @StevenBaltay Have you looked at `get_taxonomies`? 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies

Comment: Ok so to make this work im going to do a normal wordpresss search query, but if the option field is set to taxonomies, then I overide the query on the search.php page and call the get_terms query. I think this should work